# Identifying cause for (pram) wheel squeak

Tags: wheels, squeaking

Hoping mechanics is the right place to get some answers.

I have a [pram](http://babyjoggerstrollers.com.au/product/city-select/) whose front right wheel wont stop squeaking and I have no idea why.

It happens only when there is weight/pressure on the wheel. It has capped bearings and the bearings are not the problem. Just to be sure, I have had someone at the bearing shop check it out and since there is no squeak when just spinning the wheel, the bearings seem alright. There is no rub between the wheel caddy (frame) and the wheel. How do I figure out what the problem is when the wheel is squeaking only under weight (of the pram) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not have anything to do with Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.

Answer (score 3):

If the pram has spoked wheels it's likely that one or more of the spokes are loose, OR there there are a couple of spokes rubbing against each other as the wheel rotates and they flex.

Comment: They aren't spokes in the traditional sense (motor/cycle). If you'd be kind enough to click on the pram link in my question and look at the front wheel. It doesn't look like the 'spokes' can rub against each other.

Comment: Ah ok.. I didn't see the pic link first time around. In that case please check the fittings where the wheels attach to the frame, any slipping or lateral movement in those fittings/joints can also cause squeaking, especially under slight loading.

Comment: The wheel(assembled, not connected to the pram) squeaks when I manually apply weight and run it by hand on a work bench.

Comment: Ah ok.. If as you mention its not the bearings it must be either the tyres squeaking against the plastic rims as they're rotating OR the tyres themselves may have perhaps an internal friction issue or use a honeycomb type structure which is causing the squeeks.

Answer (score 3):

Bearings can behave differently "under load" compared to not under load - are they sealed bearings? There might be a small bit of dirt in there

Comment: Yes, they are sealed bearings. I did spray generous amounts of WD40 and WD40 Silicone spray (on different occasions) and spun the tyre hoping some of it will seep through and help - but it didn't. If the bearings are broken, wouldn't you straight away feel it even while just spinning the wheel on an axis (not under load) ?